# Different accuracy when splitting data with train_test_split than loading csv file afterwards

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I have build a model to predict if a customer is a business or a private customer. After training the model I predict the class of 1000 datasets which I didn’t use for the training. This prediction will be saved in a csv file.
Now I have two different behaviours:

1. **Splitting sample data in the program**

When I create the sample with `train, sample = train_test_split(train, test_size=1000, random_state=seed)` then prediction gets the same accuracy during the training (same value as validation).

2. **Splitting sample data in advance and then loading it**

But when I split the data manually before learning by taking 1000 datasets of the original csv file and copying it in a new sample csv file which I am loading before doing the prediction after learning, I got a much worse result (e.g. 76% instead of 90%).
This behaviour doesn’t make sense in my eyes since the original data (the csv file for training) was also shuffled in advanced and therefore I should get the same result.
Here is the relevant code of the mentioned case distinction:

### 1. Splitting sample data in the program

**Splitting**

```py
def getPreProcessedDatasetsWithSamples(filepath, batch_size):
    path = filepath
    data = __getPreprocessedDataFromPath(path) 
    
    train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    train, sample = train_test_split(train, test_size=1000, random_state=seed)

    train_ds = __df_to_dataset(train, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
    val_ds = __df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
    test_ds = __df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
    sample_ds = __df_to_dataset(sample, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

    return (train_ds, val_ds, test_ds, sample, sample_ds)
```

**Prediction with sample, sample_ds**

```py
def savePredictionWithSampleToFileKeras(model, outputName, sample, sample_ds):
    predictions = model.predict(sample_ds)
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(sample_ds)


    print("Accuracy of sample", accuracy)


    sample['prediction'] = predictions
    sample.to_csv("./saved_samples/" + outputName + ".csv")
```

Accuracy of sample: 90%

### 2.   Splitting sample data in advance and then loading it

**Prediction by loading csv file**

```py
def savePredictionToFileKeras(model, sampleFilePath, outputName, batch_size):
    sample_ds = preprocessing.getPreProcessedSampleDataSets(sampleFilePath, batch_size)
    sample = preprocessing.getPreProcessedSampleDataFrames(sampleFilePath)

    predictions = model.predict(sample_ds)
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(sample_ds)

    print("Accuracy of sample", accuracy)

    sample['prediction'] = predictions
    sample.to_csv("./saved_samples/" + outputName + ".csv")
```

Accuracy of sample: 77%

**EDIT**

Observation: When I load the whole data as sample data, I get the same value as the validation value as expected (ca. 90%) but when I just randomize the line order of the same file, I get a value of 82%. As my understanding the accuracy should be the same, since the files are equal.

Some additional information:
I have changed the implementation form the sequential to the functional API. I’m using Embeddings in the pre-processing (I also tried One-Hot-Encoding without success).

Comment: Did you try K fold cross-validation?

Comment: No not yet, since I don’t think that the cross validation would explain the different behaviour. Furthermore, the results don’t differ when chaining the random_state and therefore the distribution of test and training set. So I don’t think CV would help me to find the answer of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem: I am using a Tokenizer to preprocess a NAME and STREET column in a way that I am converting each word to a value which indicates how often the word occurs. In the case I am using `train_test_split` I use the same overall words of all data for converting the words, but when I am loading the sample dataset afterwards I use only the words which occurs in the sample dataset. For instance, the word “family” could be the most used word overall but just the third in the sample dataset and therefore the encoding would be totally wrong.
After using the same tokenizer instance for all data, I get the same high accuracy for all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Both the above methods don't predict correct accuracy. Accuracy will be good measurement only if your data is balanced. For unbalanced data it is not good measure and it wont be correct always. each time you change the accuracy will change.
You should be using K fold cross validation firstly so that all data points will be used for training model. In case if your data set is not balanced you can try different balance techniques like over sampling or under sampling on the train data and validate the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you understand as unbalanced? For Instance, my data consist of 60% of Class A and 40% of Class B, do you consider this as unbalanced?

Comment: The thing is that I can’t understand why only the accuracy of the manually loaded data change (in a worse manner) and not the data of the ``train_test_split``? For example, every time I use a different Distribution over the Train/Validation/Test Sets I get the same result e.g. 90%. So that’s the reason why I don’t see the need to use CV since the accuracy is always the same, doesn’t matter which Train/Validation/Test distribution I use. I try to understand why this is not the case by manually loading the data.