# Loading & splitting same training data but getting different results

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

So I'm trying to manually split my training data into separate batches such that I can easily **access** them via **indexing**, and not relying on `DataLoader` to split them up for me, since that way I won't be able to access the **individual** batches by indexing. So I attempted the following:

```
train_data = datasets.ANY(root='data', transform=T_train, download=True)
BS = 200
num_batches = len(train_data) // BS
sequence = list(range(len(train_data)))
np.random.shuffle(sequence)  # To shuffle the training data
subsets = [Subset(train_data, sequence[i * BS: (i + 1) * BS]) for i in range(num_batches)]
train_loader = [DataLoader(sub, batch_size=BS) for sub in subsets]  # Create multiple batches, each with BS number of samples
```

Which works during training just fine.

However, when I attempted another way to manually split the training data I got different end results, even with **all** the same parameters and the following settings ensured:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

I only split the training data the following way this time:

```
train_data = list(datasets.ANY(root='data', transform=T_train, download=True))  # Cast into a list
BS = 200
num_batches = len(train_data) // BS
np.random.shuffle(train_data)  # To shuffle the training data
train_loader = [DataLoader(train_data[i*BS: (i+1)*BS], batch_size=BS) for i in range(num_batches)]
```

But this gives me different results than the first approach, even though (*I believe*) that both approaches are identical in manually splitting the training data into batches. I even tried **not shuffling** at all and loading the data just as it is, but I still got different results (85.2% v.s 81.98% accuracy). I even manually checked that the loaded images from the batches match; and are the same using both methods.

The training scheme used in both ways:

```
for e in trange(epochs):
    for loader in train_loader:
        for x, y in loader:
            x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(m1(x), y)
            loss.backward()
            optim.step()
            scheduler.step()
            optim.zero_grad()
```

Can somebody please explain to me why these differences arise (and if there's a better way)?

**UPDATE:**

`T_train` transformation contains some random transformations (H_flip, crop) and when using it along with the first `train_loader` the time taken during training was: 24.79s/it, while the second `train_loader` took: 10.88s/it (even though both have the exact same number of parameters updates/steps). So I decided to remove the random transformations from `T_train`; then the time taken using the first `train_loader` was: 16.99s/it, while the second `train_loader` took: 10.87s/it. So somehow, the second `train_loader` still took the **same** time (with or without the random transformations). Thus, I decided to visualize the image outputs from the second `train_loader` to make sure that the transformations were applied, and indeed they were! So this is really confusing and I'm not quite why they're giving different results.

Comment: Is this question same? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359473/15358800

Comment: @Bhargav not quite, but thanks for the reference

Comment: Have you checked the first datapoint from both methods is the same?  train_data[sequence[0]] in the first method and train_data[0] after shuffled in the second method.

Comment: Also. it would be useful to have the training code.

Comment: There are more things that can affect the seeds, `random.seed(seed)` and 
  `torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)`. You can check here https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pytorch_lightning/utilities/seed.html#seed_everything .

Comment: @joe32140 hey thanks a lot for your input! Yes I did check that both batches contain the same images in the exact same order using both methods (removed the shuffling, but still got drastically different results). I also added an update below that might be of help. Thank you